# Construct isomorphism $M\cong M/N+N$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, module-isomorphism

I think that $M\cong M/N+N$ holds, where $M,N$ are $R$ modules for a certain ring $R$.

This equality makes sense to me, for example if I take $M=\mathbb{Z}$ and $N=2\mathbb{Z}$ it makes sense. However I cannot construct an isomorphism to show that this actually holds. Can you help me?

Comment: This is false, and your example is not an example, since $\mathbb{Z}$ does not have any submodule isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: This idea is formalized as https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Extension_of_a_module.